# Combine DataFrame as JSON with additional data

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to combine some meta information together with a Pandas DataFrame as a JSON string.

I can call `df.to_json(orient='values')` to get the DataFrame's data as array, but how do I combine it with some additional data?

```
result = {
  meta: {'some': 'meta info'},
  data: [[dataframe.values], [list], [...]]
}
```

I could also ask: How do I merge a Python object (`meta: {...}`) into a serialised JSON string (`df.to_json()`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always convert JSON into Python data.

```
import json

df_json = df.to_json(orient='values') # JSON

py_data = json.loads( df_json ) # Python data

result['extra_data'] = py_data # merge data

json_all = json.dumps( result ) # JSON again
```

---

**EDIT:**

I found better solution - use `pandas.json.dumps`
Standard module `json` got problem with numpy numbers used in dictionary made by pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

result = { 'meta': {'some': 'meta info'} }

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [.1,.2,.3]], columns=('a','b','c'))

#result['extra_data'] = df.to_dict() # as dictonary

result['extra_data'] = df 

print pd.json.dumps( result )
```

result

```
{
  "extra_data":{
      "a":{"0":1.0,"1":0.1},
      "c":{"0":3.0,"1":0.3},
      "b":{"0":2.0,"1":0.2}
  },
  "meta":{"some":"meta info"}
}
```

or

```
import pandas as pd

result = { 'meta': {'some': 'meta info'} }

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [.1,.2,.3]], columns=('a','b','c'))

df_dict = df.to_dict()

df_dict['extra_data'] = result

print pd.json.dumps( df_dict )
```

result

```
{
   "a":{"0":1.0,"1":0.1},
   "c":{"0":3.0,"1":0.3},
   "b":{"0":2.0,"1":0.2}
   "extra_data":{"meta":{"some":"meta info"}},
}
```

Comment: True, but this defeats the purpose of using pandas' fast `to_json` method. I haven't tested it, but I guess it will be faster to attach `df.values` to `result` and then jsonify than going through the trouble of serialising/unserialising and serialising again.

Comment: See new solution in answer.